# Duplicate a pop window display on dual monitors

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms, multiple-monitors

I have a customer requirement, where they would like to duplicate a pop up window display in the primary and the secondary monitor as well, is this possible? And is there a solution that is able to achieve this using a web application?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the only way to do it is to use JavaScript to generate two popups and then use CSS to push the popups to the correct locations.

The problem I would think you are going to run into is knowing whether or not you have two displays to manage or not.